# Adding page numbers and line numbers to quarto documents

Tags: r, quarto

I am trying to render a quarto document as a docx, but it does not seem to be possible to add page numbers or line numbers in the footer region of the document. I tried to edit that in the reference document, but it does not work. Any solutions?

Comment: Can you share an example of the YAML options for your Quarto document that you currently have?

Answer (score 0):

Just follow the instructions [here](https://quarto.org/docs/output-formats/ms-word-templates.html) in the case of the Word Template. Then for the case of the `custom-reference-doc.docx` in relation to inserting page numbers follow the instructions [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/insert-page-numbers-9f366518-0500-4b45-903d-987d3827c007).

Then build your document where the yaml will be something like this:

```yaml
---
title: "Test document"
format:
  docx:
    reference-doc: custom-reference-doc.docx
editor: visual
---
```

Here is a screenshot of the result using a `test.docx`:

[image]

Furthermore these are the contents of the folder that contains the `test.docx` document:

```
    .gitignore
    custom-reference-doc.docx
    README.md
    test.docx
    test.qmd
    test.Rproj
```

If you have difficulties with this answer I create a repository with the necessary files to replicate the result [here](https://github.com/luifrancgom/test_word) in GitHub.